# How can I have Vim use absolute line numbers when I'm typing in the command line and relative otherwise?

Tags: vim

I'd like a simple augroup that switches all buffers to absolute line numbers (for Ex commands) when I go into the command window

my current code is:

```
augroup cmdWin
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdwinEnter  *  setglobal  nornu   
  autocmd CmdwinLeave *  setglobal  rnu 
augroup END
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can use relative numbers in Ex commands: `:-8,+12m$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:setglobal` won't work, because it just sets the future default, but doesn't update the values in existing windows. You need to apply this for all current windows, normally with `:windo`, but changing windows is a bad idea when the special command-line window is involved. Therefore, we toggle the option(s) "at a distance" via `setwinvar()` and a loop:

```
augroup cmdWin
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdwinEnter * for i in range(1,winnr('$')) | call setwinvar(i, '&number', 1) | call setwinvar(i, '&relativenumber', 0) | endfor
    autocmd CmdwinLeave * for i in range(1,winnr('$')) | call setwinvar(i, '&number', 0) | call setwinvar(i, '&relativenumber', 1) | endfor
augroup END
```

This toggles between `nu + nornu` and `nonu + rnu`; adapt the logic if you want to keep `nu` on and just toggle `rnu`.

Comment: Maybe saving the `&nu` and `&rnu` values to window variables and then restoring them would be nicer.

Comment: @PeterRincker Certainly, this can be made more convenient and robust. I'm just giving an answer, no complete plugin :-)

Comment: heh, if I ever get better at VimL, I'm going to make a complete plugin and credit you Ingo, assuming that's cool

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to look at two vim plugins:

- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4212
- https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/vim-numbertoggle