# How can I set nornu/rnu for CmdwinEnter/CmdwinLeave

Tags: vim, vi

I've want to make `relativenumber` disabled in the [command-line mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#CmdwinEnter). Because somethings I need know the absolute linenumbers in the command-line mode (goto someline by `:<line_number>`)

my setting as below, **but it won't work...**

```
  autocmd CmdwinEnter * set norelativenumber
  autocmd CmdwinLeave * set relativenumber
```

Somehow, this setting ([Get fome here](https://github.com/jrk-/dotvim/blob/master/vimrc.d/.vimrc#L74)) work fine:

```
  autocmd CmdwinEnter * let b:ei_save = &eventignore | set eventignore=CursorHold,InsertEnter
  autocmd CmdwinLeave * let &eventignore = b:ei_save
```

**I want to know why my `CmdwinEnter`/`CmdwinLeave` for **relavitenumber` didn't work, and how can I make it.**

---

By the way, 
This method **works fine** in [Insert mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#InsertEnter) by:

```
  autocmd InsertEnter * set norelativenumber
  autocmd InsertLeave * set relativenumber
```

And:

- My Vim version is: 7.4.250
- [Here](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc#L420) is my whole vimrc.
- This situation happens in my both Win7 and Linux system.
- Yes, I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415962/how-can-i-have-vim-use-absolute-line-numbers-when-im-typing-in-the-command-line), and the "best answer" doesn't works either.

Comment: How about using relative ranges for your ex commands? e.g. `:+3,+7j!` or `:+3` for your goto to a line

Comment: That works too. I just confused that, `set eventignore=CursorHold,InsertEnter` could work for **CmdwinEnter**, but why `set norelativenumber` cannot?

Answer (score 2):

you got confused by the event name: `CmdwinEnter/Leave`, they would be triggered by enter/leaving **command line window**, not command line **mode**. `:h cmdwin`

I guess with your current setting, in command mode, if you press `ctrl-f` (entering cmd-win), you should see the line number change, and it would be applied on the `command line window`, you have to find the window id of your main editing, to change the setting.

To catch the "event" to entering command line **mode**, you could map normal mode `:` to a function, there, you could do preprocessing.

For catching the "event" of leaving cmd mode, you have to check the current mode all the time, if it is changed into normal.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer first. I have few questions, 1. the windows linenumber always **absolute number** by press `ctrl+f` (after enter cmd-win), no matter setting `autocmd CmdwinEnter * set norelativenumber` and `autocmd CmdwinLeave * set relativenumber`. You can try that too

Comment: 2. `autocmd CmdwinEnter * let b:ei_save = &eventignore | set eventignore=CursorHold,InsertEnter`, this command works (Cursor disappear) after I just press `:`. Why `set norelativenumber` cannot?

Comment: 3. How can I find the "the window id of your main editing, to change the setting."